# How to use regular with Shell script

Tags: json, shell, sed

Run

```
curl http://localhost:3000/
```

I will get an array output like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "wred": {
      "lsd": "8040baf7aded3319b0dec433b2461"
    },
    "node": "dfsafafafaf="
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "wred": {
      "lsd": "e6b3a11581a800d"
    },
    "node": "fdsafzxcvx="
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "wred": {
      "lsd": "d3319b0dec433b2461"
    },
    "node": "hlkkjjkhjas="
  }
]
```

I want to get `name1` via Shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
get_name() {
  curl --silent "http://localhost:3000/" |
  grep '"name":' |
  sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'                                 
}
echo `get_name`
```

And I get result like this

```
name1 name2 name3
```

Please help me, many thanks.

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse JSON, rather use a proper parser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Comment: @Cid No, I don't want to use JSON.

Comment: You are already using JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the curl in JSON format. Use `jq` tool to extract. While technically you can process some JSON file with sed, this is risky: sed is line oriented, and JSON is structured. There is no guarantee that the JSON file will be formatted in a specific way.

```
curl ... | jq -r '.[0].name'
```

Do 'man jq' to get full information. Short version:
* The '.[0]' will select the first entry of the array
* The 'name' select the name element
* The '-r' produces 'raw' output - stripping the quotes.